# jquery function to do manipulation on data source from sharepoint list to pie chart

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, charts

Actually I'm fetching data from share point list and creating jquery pie chart.I did some looping to eliminate the duplicate values repeating in the pie chart.Its working fine now.. But i need to know that ,"is there any jquery library function which does this function automatically?? ".

Thanks in advance.help me out.

Comment: Give me an example of the duplicate values you're trying to remove. Are they duplicates in the SharePoint list?

Comment: In my sharepoint list i have data like this,  Apple-4,Orange-3,Apple-3,Grapes-4,Apple-3,Orange-5. my pie chart should give as Apple-10,Orange-8,grapes-4. I have done it with manually looping in jquery. but i want to know  that "is there any jquery lib which does this function??".